# Permission Denial Issue even after adding the required permission in manifest file

Tags: android, android-permissions

Here is the Error Log:

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity }  requires com.android.setting.permission.ALLSHARE_CAST_SERVICE
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2329)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1426)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3513)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3474)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3716)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3684)
```

Manifest file with Permission:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.setting.permission.ALLSHARE_CAST_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a marshmallow device?

Comment: I am getting the issue only in samsung galaxy devices(4.3,4.4)

Answer (score 0):

if your app is having target API level `23` make sure user grants the permission before  using them. See [RunTimePermission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are testing this application on samsung device because this permission is only worked on samsung device. As per my knowledge such permission is not exists in the android permission list.
Below is the permission list from android.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Hope this will help you.